# How to give the file path in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, download

I am downloading a file from one drive to another drive in my local system. This is the code which I have used:

```
upload.js:
   var fs = require('fs')
   var newPath = "E:\\Thevan";
   var oldPath = "E:\\Thevan\\Docs\\something.mp4";

   exports.uploadFile = function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile(oldPath, function(err, data) {
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
        fs.unlink(oldPath, function(){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);
        });
      });
   });
};

app.js:
   var express = require('express'), // fetch express js library
   upload = require('./upload'); // fetch upload.js you have just written
   var app = express();
   app.get('/upload', upload.uploadFile); 
   app.listen(3000);
```

When I run the above code.. It gives error as "Error: EISDIR, open 'E:\Thevan'".
How to give the path or anything went wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to work with paths - use `path` module ([API](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html)):

Or with `path` module:

```
var path = require('path');
path.join('E:','Thevan','Some File.mp4');
```

It also fix more issues if you switch to Linux.

But you have an other problem - you pass `DIRNAME` instead of `FILENAME` to `writeFile` function. I think you mean:

```
var newPath = "E:\\Thevan\\something.mp4";
var oldPath = "E:\\Thevan\\Docs\\something.mp4";
```

Comment: suppose if the file name has space means (e.g. New Song.MP4) how to give it along with path.join?

Comment: yes man.. it worked... but i found one very strange error.. when i first moved the file, it worked and i played the file.. When i try for the second time, one new file is created in the new path, but it is not fully downloaded. Only 1kb is downloaded.. what may be the reason?

Comment: sorry man. leave the last comment.. it works fine.. the problem is when download the file in the old path gets moved. so in the old path, the file was not exists thats why the file is not downloaded during the second time...

Comment: I recomend you also see [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra)

Comment: Can it possible to download the file by keeping the original file in its old path itself?